# Stuck with nested serializer using Django Rest Framework and default user

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

The models and serializers are described in the pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/ZxzxWY7V

In my database I have a user which also has a member profile and a set of credentials attached to it.

Now... when I run this as is and try to pull a user using the AuthUserModelSerializer I get the member and the credentials, but the MemberProfile is not passed!  I can't figure out why.  I'm not sure if it's because the MemberProfile is a 1 to 1 relationship (Tried changing it to Foreign key to test), or if there is something wrong with my model / serializer.  Below is an example response from the API:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "eric",
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$20000$xA5jPJVAByjo$i/FpmosJgsppVH4o5ctryDppOyG1ZaB+tQ2VIa+jFX0=",
    "email": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "is_staff": true,
    "is_active": true,
    "date_joined": "2015-06-17T00:10:24.514894Z",
    "credentials": [
        {
            "credential_type": "O",
            "credential_number": "23423423",
            "date_received": "2015-06-17T00:27:49.367446Z",
            "is_verified": true,
            "date_verified": "2015-06-17T00:27:46Z",
            "document_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/members/images/credentials/e990868659524470aadb9996c68384ba.ext/logo11w.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:
Fix was to change

```
class AuthUserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    credentials = CredentialSerializer(many=True)
    member = MemberProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
```

to

```
class AuthUserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    credentials = CredentialSerializer(many=True)
    member = MemberProfileSerializer(read_only=True, source='profile')
```

Thank you Linovia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default DRF will look at an attribute on the `User` model named after the serializer's field (`member` here). However the related name is `profile`.

This can be worked around by passing the `source="profile"` to your `MemberProfileSerializer`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  For anyone who wants clarification, on my nested serializer I had to add that command.  Fixed it above now.